# skip blank lines with csv.reader

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I need to read in a .txt file, find the row where labels are, return a list (or other iterable) of those labels plus the index of the next line. In this particular program, I use it the first time to open the file and return the labels (which are consistent) and the index of the next line for the purpose of identifying what to open with np.genfromtxt. The subsequent uses are just to determine the index only.

Sometimes, the technician will put an extra carriage return in when entering test parameters and it results in an extra blank line. When that happens, I get an empty set instead of labels. In [TFM](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) it seems that csv.reader takes that blank line as EOF, but I don't see how to tell it to keep checking.

Is there a way to make it do that?
Is there a better way to accomplish what I want?

---

```
def get_labels(filename):
    index = 0    
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:    
        dialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(f.read())        
        f.seek(0)        
        reader = csv.reader(f, dialect)
        for row in reader:
            if 'TimeStamp (s)' not in row:
                index += 1
            else:
                return row, index + 1
```

Update:
I'm trying to figure out the strip function, but I think this is clunky and not the way to go. Here's what I've tried so far:

```
def strip(filename):
    with open(otherfile, 'wb') as o:    
        with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
            for line in f:
                if line == '\n':
                    continue
                else:
                    o.write(line)
    f.close()
    o.close()    
    return o
```

Comment: Is the extra carriage return at the beginning of the file? If so, doesn't that mean that you are applying the sniffer to a blank line, which will give a bad dialect?

Comment: @G.Meyer Are you sure that `sniff` cannot handle empty newlines at the beginning?

Comment: Btw: you don't have to pass the whole file to the `Sniffer`. The sniffer just requires one (partial) row to guess the delimiters etc, so, usually `1024` bytes are more than enough. If the csv file is very big you are adding a lot of overhead for nothing.

Comment: The files are about 32 kb...  and the blank line is never the first one. The tech fills out several parameters. The blank line is always between 4 and 12, I believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick way to solve the problem is a second function that strips empty lines. You can use `itertools.ifilter` to do the job:

```
import itertools

def get_labels(filename):
    index = 0    
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        sample = ''.join(x[0] for x in zip(itertools.ifilter(strip, f), range(4)))
        dialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(sample)        
        f.seek(0)        
        reader = csv.reader(itertools.ifilter(strip, f), dialect)
        for row in reader:
            if 'TimeStamp (s)' not in row:
                index += 1
            else:
                return row, index + 1
```

You could write your own strip function instead of using filter:

```
def strip_lines(iterable, maxlines=None):
    for i, line in enumerate(iterable):
        if line.strip() and (maxlines is None or maxlines > i):
            yield line

def get_labels(filename):
    index = 0    
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        dialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(''.join(strip_lines(f, 4))
        f.seek(0)        
        reader = csv.reader(strip_lines(f), dialect)
        for row in reader:
            if 'TimeStamp (s)' not in row:
                index += 1
            else:
                return row, index + 1
```

Comment: I'm having trouble writing a strip function. If I had that, I wouldn't need to use itertools at all, would I?

Comment: Yes, you could easily write your own strip function also. I'll add an example.

Comment: Thanks for the example! I'm trying to figure out if there's something else that's currently breaking it - I'm getting "NaN" at the beginning of the arrays for the file that has the space in it.

Comment: I see - when the strip_lines function pulls out those lines, the original file still has them and the index doesn't iterate. In the first answer, I don't understand what the "strip" is - my IDE said it was unknown.

Comment: @mauve, I see what you mean... I didn't account for the need to lookahead and get the index of the next line. It'll need some wtweeks